# MSMQ: How do you send a msg from transactional dead letter queue to a private queue on remote machine

Tags: msmq, msmq-transaction

Windows Server 2012

MSMQ 6 Workgroup Mode

We've had issues trying to recover MSMQ messages that were sent to the transaction dead letter queue.  We've tried moving them to the outbound queue, the message seems to send fine (even the Event Log says so) however it never gets to the destination queue.

After trial and error we've figured out how to get them to another queue on the same server but not to the destination queue on a remote server.  We don't want to lose anymore messages.  Does anyone have any suggestion on how we can deliver these messages?

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, it's a one time problem with some number of messages you already have in MSMQ, and not general connectivity issue between machines? If so, you should be able to solve it with some MSMQ management tool. Disclaimer: I'm the author of one such tool - QueueExplorer. I don't know what other tools can do, but with QueueExplorer you can copy/paste or drag/drop messages to another machine opened in separate tab/window. In order to do that QueueExplorer has to perform MSMQ Send operation, so messages will have to pass through MSMQ between these two machines. 
So if there's still that issue that prevented original delivery you'll still be stuck. In that case you can save all messages to a file, transfer it to another machine through file system and load it there to whichever queue they should go. This is obviusly just a manual workaround for one time situation. Btw. this could be done in QueueExplore's trial mode.

If however problem is with connectivity and messages always end up in dead letter queue, it's better to check them from Computer Management. It's one area where it's better than our tool - you can turn on "Class" column and see reason why messages couldn't be delivered. For instance if you see "The time-to-be-received has elapsed" you'll know what's the problem.